# Aim TTi EL302RT PSU : understanding the specs, and comparing

Tags: power-supply

I'm considering to dump some $ on a desk power supply for myself. I'm looking Aim TTI EL302RT, with data sheet here:
[EL302RT](http://resources.aimtti.com/datasheets/AIM-EL-R+EX-R_series_DC_power_supplies_data_sheet-Iss1.pdf)

Few questions I have:

1. Are all the 3 channels isolated, have their own ground? Even that middle one which goes upto 5V?
2. The measured or displayed voltages, spec says resolution is 10mV, but the output regulation performance I'm not sure I understand it is spec'ed : it says, Line regulation "< 0.01% for of maximum output for 10% line change". So does this mean, for a 30V line (max V output), if I do a 10% change on the dial knob(s) , the output V will change by 30000 mV * 0.001 = 30 mV ..?   It doesn't , it seems, say anything about the smallest change I can make - can I make only a 1% change with Fine knob ?   If 30mV is 10%,  I hope then if I can change by 1% that's a 3mV change..?
3. And also I wanted to ask for your experienced opinion, do you think EL302RT is much better than Rigol DP-832 or other way? Spec for this Rigol here : [Rigol DP-832](http://www.emona.com.au/component/phocadownload/category/101-11%20Laboratory%20Power%20Supplies?download=1144:DP800). This Rigol seems very popular here for home-lab / semi-professional, and good reviews.  But at least on line voltage regulation, if I understand it correct, *might* be slightly less accurate - <0.01% + 2mV - but, it's digital, so perhaps I can sure step in 1% adjustments, unlike on the knobs on the EL302RT...
   Also this Rigol has only 2 isolated channels I think, 2 share ground.

So I was about to commit to DP-832, but then I saw this EL302RT, and, I remembered as one of my employers had it in their lab.  So now I'm not sure.

Your answers would really help me out.

Comment: Asking for recommendations of specific products is off-topic for this site.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson Ok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you thought of asking TTi Directly?

Email: info@aimtti.com

They usually respond very quickly and will pass the question onto the design engineer if nobody in sales is sure of an answer.  I used to work for them and have designed some of the power supplies on that data sheet though not this particular model.

But to answer your questions directly.

> Are all the 3 channels isolated, have their own ground? Even that middle one which goes up to 5V?

Yes each output is independent and floating.  The front panel shows the level of isolation from earth (to either 0V or output) which is 300V.  It is not obvious from the specification but this also applies between any two outputs. This may not be relevant in this case as its max output is 30V.

> The measured or displayed voltages, spec says resolution is 10mV, but the output regulation performance I'm not sure I understand it is spec'ed : it says, Line regulation "< 0.01% for of maximum output for 10% line change". So does this mean, for a 30V line (max V output), if I do a 10% change on the dial knob(s) , the output V will change by 30000 mV * 0.001 = 30 mV ..? It doesn't , it seems, say anything about the smallest change I can make - can I make only a 1% change with Fine knob ? If 30mV is 10%, I hope then if I can change by 1% that's a 3mV change..?

Regulation and metering are separate things.

Metering:
Resolution 10mV simply because that's the value of the lowest digit.
Accuracy: 0.3% ± 3 digits

To understand what this means let's say the output is actually 30.00V

30V - 0.3% = 29.91V minus 4 digits is 29.87
30V + 0.3% = 30.09V plus  4 digits is 30.13

The display can show anything between 29.87 and 30.13 and still be in specification.

Lets say the output is actually 0V, ±0.3% is still zero volt so in theory the display can be between -0.04 and 0.04 and still be in specification. This model does not display negative values however so will never show <0.00.  The bottom end is calibrated in the factory using a small positive voltage so it displays a very small number to allow for this.

Line regulation and load regulation are a measure of how much the output is allowed to change as the mains and load change but the display is based on what is actually being output.

Setting resolution is purely analogue so you can change the output by less than a mV if your hands are steady enough.

> And also I wanted to ask for your experienced opinion, do you think EL302RT is much better than Rigol DP-832 or other way? ...

No comment, I have never used this Rigol supply.  I can personally vouch for the TTi model but Rigol also make nice products.  On this site we are also not supposed to make shopping recommendations.

Comment: thank you very much for the explanations, and apologies about the product recommendation.  Just to clarify something:  30V-0.3%=29.91V "minus 4 digits" it seems , it just -4 decimal.. (or just 4 millivolts)?  (not just any 4 digits, like 1234). Wording a bit confusing to me :)

Comment: "Setting resolution is purely analogue so you can change the output by less than a mV if your hands are steady enough"    Ok, so I guess part of my questions is,  is it possible to set output in smallest steps on this meter using it's controls (knobs) , say just by 5mV? I have a cheap supply now, and arguably i cannot increase/decrease voltage in any steps smaller than say ~300mV or so, and its very tricky as I have only once adjuster and even touching it may change output.

Comment: I don't know if you will look again here, but, about the TTi PSU: does one need those remote sense lines, when it only can output 2A ?

Comment: 1 digit is the smallest unit that can be displayed, so with a change of 1 digit the last digit will change by one.

Comment: Remote sensing is provided on most TTi power supplies to allow for drops down the cable.  If not used it is the output terminal voltage.  If you have short enough and fat enough cables, so drop is negligible, then you don't need to use it.

Comment: For all TTi products when they use the term 'digits' they mean the least significant digit displayed. On this model it's 0.01 so 10mV.  Next time I see the sales director I will mention it to him.  I don't think it will make a difference for any existing data sheets or manuals but may go into future products e.g "+/- 0.3% plus 4 digits (40mV)".

Comment: @jusaca ok. it's display granularity is 10mV (2 decimals ), so , err, then 1 digit change is 10 mV...

Comment: @WarrenHill hey thank you very much for explanations.  But, do you think it's worth paying extra for remote sensing, when your power supply only is rated to say 2 - 3A output? (as I understand, too low amps to regulate the output).   Because remote sensing is extra feature for some other manufacturers, some ( say Rigol, as I checked) only put it on some / or more expensive models that can output higher amps. And I read some places (including TTi page web page on sensing https://www.aimtti.com/remote-sense)  you don't need it for low currents. What is your view? Is it worth say extra $200?